# Edit menu item title from edit page/post

Tags: posts, menus, pages

After we save a post/page, a new menu item is created (with the same title) in the navigation that we have created in `nav-menus.php`.

If we need to change the menu item title, we need to go to `nav-menus.php` and change it to something else.

Is it possible to have some text field, for example in the edit post/page, where we can write the menu item title that we want for this page/post without needing to edit `nav-menus.php` each time?

This can really save a lot of time for users.

**Here is the full and working code! Thanks to @Howdy_McGee**

```
/**
 * Adds a box to the main column on the Page edit screens.
 */
function menu_item_title_changer_add_meta_box() {

    $screens = array( 'page' );

    foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {

        add_meta_box(
            'menu_item_title_changer',
            __( 'Menu item title changer', 'webic-admin' ),
            'menu_item_title_changer_callback',
            $screen
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'menu_item_title_changer_add_meta_box' );

/**
 * Prints the box content.
 * 
 * @param WP_Post $post The object for the current post/page.
 */
function menu_item_title_changer_callback( $post ) {

    // Add a nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field( 'menu_item_title_changer_meta_box', 'menu_item_title_changer_meta_box_nonce' );

    /*
     * Use get_post_meta() to retrieve an existing value
     * from the database and use the value for the form.
     */
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_menu_item_title_changer', true );

    echo '<label for="menu_item_title_changer_field">';
    _e( 'Description for this field', 'myplugin_textdomain' );
    echo '</label> ';
    echo '<input type="text" id="menu_item_title_changer_field" name="menu_item_title_changer_field" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" size="25" />';
}

/**
 * When the post is saved, saves our custom data.
 *
 * @param int $post_id The ID of the post being saved.
 */
function menu_item_title_changer_save_meta_box_data( $post_id, $post ) {

    /*
     * We need to verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization,
     * because the save_post action can be triggered at other times.
     */

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['menu_item_title_changer_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['menu_item_title_changer_meta_box_nonce'], 'menu_item_title_changer_meta_box' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

    } else {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    /* OK, it's safe for us to save the data now. */

    // Make sure that it is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['menu_item_title_changer_field'] ) ) {
        return;
    }


    // here is the code here it is working bug my system stack after i click save "save"
    if( 'page' == $post->post_type ) {

        // Check Nonces

        $nav_item = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type'      => 'nav_menu_item',        // Nav Post Type
            'posts_per_page' => 1,                      // We only expect 1 result, if any
            'meta_key'       => '_menu_item_object_id', // With our Meta Key
            'meta_value'     => $post->ID               // And our Correct Page
        ) );

        if( $nav_item->have_posts() ) {                 // Ensure something was found
            wp_update_post( array(                      // Update the `nav_menu_item` Post Title
                'ID'            => $nav_item->posts[0]->ID,
                'post_title'    => htmlspecialchars( sanitize_text_field( $_POST['menu_item_title_changer_field'] ) )
            ) );
        }

        // Update Page Meta
    }

    // Sanitize user input.
    $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['menu_item_title_changer_field'] );

    // Update the meta field in the database.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_menu_item_title_changer', $my_data );

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'menu_item_title_changer_save_meta_box_data', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried creating a [metabox](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee i know how to create metabox this is not the problem here. but i dont know what to do next. how can i update by code the menu item title that connected to this page/post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you add a new item to WordPress Menu ( `Appearance -> Menu` ) it creates a new Post of Post Type `nav_menu_item` and gets assigned a post meta called `_menu_item_object_id` with the main Post ID.

For example, if I create a page called "Home" it gets assigned a Post ID of `2`. Now, when I go to Menus and add the page to a menu, WordPress creates a new post of post type `nav_menu_item`, assigns the title to "Home", gives it a ID in the database of `3` and assigns post meta `_menu_item_object_id = 2`. If we want to change the title to "Homepage" in Menus, it would change the Post ID `3` to title "Homepage".

If we wanted to change the title via metabox we would need to find Post Type `nav_menu_item` that has post_meta `_menu_item_object_id` with the same ID as our current page. I'm assuming you already have a metabox setup, are checking post types, and nonces.

```
if( 'page' == $post->post_type ) {

    // Check Nonces

    $nav_item = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'nav_menu_item',        // Nav Post Type
        'posts_per_page' => 1,                      // We only expect 1 result, if any
        'meta_key'       => '_menu_item_object_id', // With our Meta Key
        'meta_value'     => $post->ID               // And our Correct Page
    ) );

    if( $nav_item->have_posts() ) {                 // Ensure something was found
        wp_update_post( array(                      // Update the `nav_menu_item` Post Title
            'ID'            => $nav_item->posts[0]->ID,
            'post_title'    => htmlspecialchars( sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_textbox_name'] ) )
        ) );
    }

    // Update Page Meta
}
```

At the end of the above code, you would also want to update the Pages post meta to the new title so you can re-display it in the metabox textbox which makes it easier for the user to update in the future.

---

Alternatively, if you want to update the metabox textbox whenever a user adds a new Item to the Menu you can reverse the process:

```
if( 'nav_menu_item' == $post->post_type ) {
    // Check Nonces

    $added_id   = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true ); // This may or may not be a Page ID
    $type       = get_post_field( 'post_type', $added_id );

    if( 'page' == $type ) {
        // Update Page Metabox Textbox Here with `$post->post_title`
    }
}
```

Comment: wow... thanks! @Howdy_McGee i will try this and let you know.

Comment: i have check the code and all works when i put the code in "save_post" action but this stack all the system. if i just put this code to functions.php nothing happens (the menu item title don't get updated). i missing something?

Comment: i have update the question with full code. with this code after i click "save" all stack but the menu item title get updated with the text field.

Comment: @need-help - The reason it's not working is because you're not passing the `$post` object to `save_post` hook - [Developer Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/). If you don't want to pass `$post` you need to change `if( 'page' == $post->post_type )` to instead use `$_POST['post_type']` and change any other instances of `$post` in my code.

Comment: thanks i didn't see that. i have update my question with full working code! thanks!